# ¿Cómo sacar el mayor número de un ArrayList guardado en un objeto para imprimir los datos como toString?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que debo recoger los datos de alumnos, y sacar el mayor de los alumnos por pantalla.

Sería algo como esto(cogería el toString creado en mi objeto para Alumnos):

```
El alumno mayor es:
Nombre: Pepe, edad: 45, altura 157
```

Para este ejercicio he realizado un ArrayList que guarda los datos de cada pregunta dentro del add del objeto.

```
        listadoAlumnos.add(new Alumnes(nombre,edat,altura));
```

El ejercicio en si está correcto, pero he realizado un método para sacar el alumno mayor y funciona erróneamente,al colocar el primer alumno si su edad es mayor a la del segundo alumno, el código responde bien y dice que el primero es mayor, el fallo viene cuando le digo que el segundo alumno, tercer alumno etc. es mayor que los demás, ya que no imprime resultado alguno, no termino de ver cómo solucionar el fallo, en este metodo recorro el ArrayList y comparo la edad.

```
public static void mayor(int edat) { //metodo para mostrar por pantalla el alumno de mayor edad
        System.out.println("El alumno de mayor edad es:");
        for(Alumnes al: listadoAlumnos) {
            if(al.getEdat()> edat) {
                System.out.println(al.toString()+"\n");
            }
        }

    }
```

He tratado de ser breve al colocar mi código pero si se requiere de más código para ver el fallo sin problema amplío la pregunta con el código.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vale si vas lo que buscas es sacar el elemento mayor del array te recomiendo que definas una variable con valor 0 y lo compares con el primer elemento, si este es mayor lo guaradas en la nueva variable y luego esto lo continuas comparando con los demas elementos, nose si me entiendes.

Comment: si pero no, te entiendo creo lo que intentas decirme pero tengo dudas sobre como colocarlo en el código. a ver yo creo por ejemplo la variable aux=0, y cual comparo con esa variable? edat o al.getEdat() ? Podrías colocar un ejemplo un poco mas visual porfavor?

Comment: @azucarilla me parece que la mejor opción y de mejor performance es hacer uso de Collections.max(), además es una forma mucho más corta de codificación, agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void mayor(int edat) { //metodo para mostrar por pantalla el alumno de mayor edad
    int mayor = 0; //esta variable nos servirá como comparador
    string infoAlumno = '';//aquí guardaremos la información del alumno
    System.out.println("El alumno de mayor edad es:");
    for(Alumnes al: listadoAlumnos) {
        if(al.getEdat()> mayor) {
            mayor = al.getEdat();
            infoAlumno = al.toString();
        }
    }
  System.out.println(infoAlumno)+"\n");
}
```

En la primera iteracion se guaradará la edad del primer alumno, en la segunda se comparará la edad del primer alumno con el segundo y si es mayor se guaradará la edad del segundo alumno en la variable y así sucesivamente hasta que se acabe el bucle, quedándonos así con la información del alumno con mayor edad.

Comment: Espero que te sirva lo hice un poco con prisa :D ya me contaras

Comment: Perfecto ahora si lo entiendo!!! era simple en verdad pero al tratar con ArrayList me he cegado y no era capaz de resolver como funcionaba, jeje no te preocupes como ejemplo es perfecto!! Gracias miles :)

Comment: Me alegra, porcierto antes no lo mencione pero no llegue a ver el uso del parametro edat que recibe la función, en mi opinión no lo necesitas para lo que quieres. ;)

Comment: edat es el resultado que se recoge por Scanner, entonces yo cogia edat que estaba en otro metodo lo pasa por parametro y lo intentaba comparar con getEdat()

Comment: Entonces ya no lo necesitas para lo que querias. Te recomiendo quitarlo si no le vas a dar uso :P

Comment: Justo al decirme he modificado el código y lo he quitado jaja gracias!

Answer (score 0):

### ¿Como Obtener objeto con máximo valor de propiedad en un ArrayList de objetos?

Una forma es hacer uso de la clase [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) y su método [max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) , realizando una comparación de la propiedad `edad`, lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
 Alumnes alumno =  Collections.max(listadoAlumnos, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getEdad()));
 System.out.println("El alumno de mayor edad es:" + alumno.getEdad());
```

Ejemplo:

```
    ArrayList<Alumnes> listadoAlumnos = new ArrayList<Alumnes>();

    Alumnes a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("Martha");a.setEdad(12);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("Ioana");a.setEdad(11);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("John");a.setEdad(15);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("azucarilla");a.setEdad(22);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("Pieter");a.setEdad(17);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("Maria");a.setEdad(18);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
    a = new Alumnes();
    a.setName("Jorge");a.setEdad(14);
    listadoAlumnos.add(a);
            
    Alumnes alumno =  Collections.max(listadoAlumnos, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getEdad()));
    System.out.println("El alumno de mayor edad es \"" + alumno.getName() + "\" con " + alumno.getEdad() + " años.");
```

Salida:

```
El alumno de mayor edad es "azucarilla" con 22 años.
```

---

La otra forma es simplemente realizar la comparación de valores cuando obtienes un valor mayor a 0 lo vas comparando en un bucle determinando si es mayor al anterior, de esta forma obtendrías el objeto con el valor mayor en la propiedad `edad`:

```
public static void mayor() { //metodo para mostrar por pantalla el alumno de mayor edad
    int comparacion = 0;
    System.out.print("El alumno de mayor edad es:");
    Alumnes alumno = null; 
    for(Alumnes al: listadoAlumnos) {
        if(al.getEdad()> comparacion) {
            comparacion = al.getEdad();           
            alumno = al;
        }            
    }        
    System.out.println(alumno.toString()+"\n");
}
```